# Oracle Optimizer Statistics Advisor and its effect on tables gather statistics

Tags: oracle

Recently i am reading more about 'Optimizer Statistics Advisor' and I have done some test on my test database. It gave the below recomondation:

```
Rule Name:         UseConcurrent                                               
 Rule Description:  Use Concurrent preference for Statistics Collection         
 Finding:  The CONCURRENT preference is not used.                               

 Recommendation:  Set the CONCURRENT preference.                                
 Example:                                                                       
 dbms_stats.set_global_prefs('CONCURRENT', 'ALL');                              
 Rationale:  The system's condition satisfies the use of concurrent statistics  
             gathering. Using CONCURRENT increases the efficiency of statistics 
             gathering.
```

As I understand from [oracle base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/concurrent-statistics-collection-12cr1#:%7E:text=Concurrent%20statistics%20collection%20is%20simply,advanced%20queuing%20and%20resource%20manager.)

```
Concurrent statistics collection is simply the ability to gather statistics on multiple tables, or table partitions, at the same time. This is done using a combination of the job scheduler, advanced queuing and resource manager.
```

so this recomondation for all the database , not for the tables. What I am saying if I gather statistics for a table such remocommndation will not have any benefits correct ? Also is there a way there 'Optimizer Statistics Advisor' can be implemented on specific tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely, because one of the overall aims for the optimizer team is that for 99% of customers, the default settings of the optimizer statistics gathering mechanisms will be sufficient to ensure good plans.

This is why (for example)

- when you use CTAS, you'll get stats collected automatically on creation, so (in most cases) no need for additional steps before using table in queries.
- a table that has queries that use predicates on skewed data will ultimately end up with histograms (via SYS.COL_USAGE$) without user intervention needed
- tables without stats will get them automatically in the next run, and until then will be dynamically sampled
- tables that change by 10% will get stats picked up again on next run

and so forth. The aim is that (except in niche cases) you'll not need to "worry" about the optimizer statistics process.

Comment: In my scenario the tables are big ( hundred of millions and few billions) and other tables have huge DML on them so statistics are gathered on weekly basis which is needed. So my question above if there are some hidden way in the statistics gathering where I can enhance the table/database performance. Similar to SQL tuning advisor where some recommendation are helpful I am checking if statiscs advisor might help. I know there are other several way to enhance the performance which I am checking too.